# 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key' no Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

No Python 2, quando eu queria saber se um `dict` tinha determinada chave, eu usava o método `has_key`.

```
if kwargs.has_key("code"):
   self.code = kwargs.code
```

Porém, agora que fui rodar o mesmo script em Python 3, obtive o seguinte erro:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'

No Python 3, esse método `has_key` foi removido? Qual opção tenho agora?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O método [`dict.has_key`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins) foi removido no Python *3.x*, use o operador [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/expressions.html#in).

> Removed. `dict.has_key()` – use the `in` operator instead.

No teu caso, você pode usá-lo assim:

```
if "code" in kwargs:
   self.code = kwargs.code
```

Comment: Bacana. Pelo visto, isso dá mais performance, já que ao invés de um método vai usar um operador..

Comment: A performance é exatametne a mesma-  operadores no Python costumam chamar métodos internos. (no caso, o método `__contains__` ) - mas a recoemendação é usar a sintaxe com `in` mesmo no Python 2.

Comment: @jsbueno muito obrigado pela informação. Não sabia que era possível usar `in` em Python 2. Sempre achei que "o certo" era o `has_key`.